# Replace the first occurence of a pattern in a file that may contain a slash

Tags: text-processing, sed

Thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed) I know how to **pass a variable that contains slashes** as a pattern to sed:

`sed "s~$var~replace~g" $file`. Juste use a single-byte character in place of /.

Thanks to [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file) I also know how to **replace just the first occurrence of a pattern in a file** (not in a line):

`sed "0,/$var/s/$var/replacement/" filename`
or
`sed 0,/$var/{s/$var/replacement/} filename`

But if I do:
`sed '0,~$var~s~$var~replacement~' filename`
(or anything else that begins with 0, then no slash), I've got an error: `unknown command: '0'`.

How could I combine the two? Maybe by using awk or perl or ... ?

Comment: You need to escape custom delmiters for non-replacements. i.e `\~$var~s~$var~replacement~`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While:

```
sed "0,\~$var~s~$var~replacement~"
```

Can be used to change the regex delimiter, embedding variable expansions inside `sed` (or any other interpreter) code is a very unwise thing to do in the general case.

First, here, the delimiter is not the only character that needs to be escaped. All the regular expression operators need to as well.

But more importantly, and especially with GNU `sed`, that's a command injection vulnerability. If the content of `$var` is not under your control, it's just as bad as passing arbitrary data to `eval`.

Try for instance:

```
$ var='^~s/.*/uname/e;#'
$ echo | sed "0,\~$var~s~$var~replacement~"
Linux
```

The `uname` command was run, thankfully a harmless one... this time.

Non-GNU `sed` implementations can't run arbitrary commands, but can overwrite any file (with the `w` command), which is virtually as bad.

A more correct way is to [escape the problematic characters in `$var` first](/q/129059):

```
NL='
'
case $var in
  (*"$NL"*)
    echo >&2 "Sorry, can't handle variables with newline characters"
    exit 1
esac
escaped_var=$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g')
# and then:
sed "0,/$escaped_var/s/$escaped_var/replacement/" < file
```

Another approach is to use `perl`:

```
var=$var perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{var}\E/replacement/g && $n++ unless $n' < file
```

Note that we're not expanding the content of `$var` inside the code passed to `perl` (which would be another command injection vulnerability), but are letting `perl` expand its content as part of its regexp processing (and within `\Q...\E` which means regexp operators are not treated specially).

If `$var` contains newline characters, that may only match if there's only one at the end. Alternatively, one may pass the `-0777` option so the input be processed as a single record instead of line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Stephane's `perl` solution, `awk` can avoid the issue of protecting a 'dangerous' interpolated value with an alternate approach:

```
export pattern="anypattern" # or whatever shell quoting is needed
awk 'NR==1,$0~ENVIRON["pattern"] {sub(ENVIRON["pattern"],"replacement")} 1' input
# or gsub if you want multiple matches on the first line with any match
```

and if the data is (possibly) large and the pattern (possibly) costly, `awk` can also avoid unnecessary matching once one match has been found with a slightly different idiom:

```
awk '!x&&$0~ENVIRON["pattern"] {sub(ENVIRON["pattern"],"replacement");x=1} 1' input
# ditto
```

Reminder: `awk` (or `sed`) treats `&` in the replacement value specially; if you need an actual `&` prefix with `\` (which usually must first be shell-quoted; here it is in `''`) and similarly double an actual `\`

Comment: Or simply (for your second case) `awk '!x && sub(ENVIRON["pattern"],"replacement") {x=1};1'`