# Add single-value content of one file as additional column to another file

Tags: text-processing

I have two files. One contains several columns and rows, while the other one only contains one value:

- file1:

  ```
  abc def
  ghi jkl
  ```
- file2:

  ```
  hello
  ```

I want to add another column to `file1` that always contains the value found in `file2`. So, the output should look like this:

```
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

Can anyone help me do that?

Comment: A discussion about tagging practices [was moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129632/discussion-between-adminbee-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 4):

You can get the last line of the file with `tail`, and then pass that as an external variable to `awk`, telling `awk` to print each line and the variable:

```
$ awk -v s="$(tail -n1 file2)" '{print $0,s}' file1
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

Note that this assumes that i) you want the last line of the `file2`; if that's not the case, you can replace `tail -n1 file` with `cat "$file"`, and ii) that `file2` doesn't contain escape sequences (see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1081936) on SO).

Answer (score 3):

This will work no matter what the string is in `file2`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{x=$0; next} {print $0, x}' file2 file1
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

or if you prefer and if the string in file2 can't contain backslashes (`-v` interprets escape sequences):

```
$ awk -v x="$(< file2)" '{print $0, x}' file1
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

Here's the difference:

```
$ cat file2
hello\there

$ awk 'NR==FNR{x=$0; next} {print $0, x}' file2 file1
abc def hello\there
ghi jkl hello\there

$ awk -v x=$(< file2) '{print $0, x}' file1
abc def hello   here
ghi jkl hello   here
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a constant string you're adding there, using sed comes to mind, with the caveat that the string to add is embedded on sed's command line, so anything processed specially by sed will not be taken as-is. E.g. a `/` would taken to terminate the `s///` command, and `&` would be replaced by the pattern part.

```
$ str=$(cat file2)
$ sed -e "s/\$/ $str/" file1
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

See e.g. discussion in: [Replace the first occurence of a pattern in a file that may contain a slash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297122/170373)

Similarly with awk, though this also isn't as content-agnostic as one might think, since for strings set with `-v`, awk processes C-style backslash escapes, so the string `foo\tbar` would turn into `foo[tab]bar`, which may or may not be what you want.

```
$ str=$(cat file2)
$ awk -v str="$str" '{print $0 " " str}' < file1
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

See e.g.: [Use a shell variable in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50044/170373)

---

Or, I guess you could use other tools too, though this turned out a bit Rube Goldberg-esque. I don't know what led me into making this up:

```
$ paste file1 <( yes "$(cat file2)" ) | head -n "$(wc -l < file1)"
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

Comment: Regarding "arbitrary values..." - `file2` couldn't contain escapes sequences in the awk command since `-v` interprets those, e.g. try it if file2 contained `hello\there`. You'd have to populate the awk variable `str` from ENVIRON or ARGV for it to be taken literally, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script.

Comment: haha, I went straight to paste/yes first too!

Comment: @EdMorton, oh, right. That was the reason using envvars was a thing. I always forget that, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: FWIW my first thought was `seq + wc + paste` but I didn't complete the thought as it started looking like it might get messy  :-). I never think of `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e 'my $str="/path/to/file2".IO.lines(1); .subst(/(^.*$)/, {$0,$str}).put for lines;' file1
```

Briefly, the first (and presumably only) line of `file2` is read in to the variable `$str`, then `file1` is analyzed linewise, `subst`-ituting (really, appending) `$str` to the end of each line, even blank lines. To change the behavior to only adding "hello" to the end of a character-containing line, change `(^.*$)` to `(^.+$)`.

Sample Input:

- file1:

  ```
  abc def
  ghi jkl
  ```
- file2:

  ```
  hello
  ```

Sample Output:

```
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```

Having Raku handle both `file1` and `file2` input (instead of passage through a shell variable) *should* obviate a number of concerns regarding proper escaping of input.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/subst
https://www.raku.org

Answer (score 0):

We can do as shown and not have to worry about escaping any characters:

```
$ sed rfile2 file1 | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
abc def hello
ghi jkl hello
```